# C# DataTable as a class

Tags: c#, datatable

I need to have a datatable in C# accessible by other methods... and I am told that I need to make a datatable as a class, not as a method, like I did in the example below:

```
//my existing datatable method     
public DataTable Conditions(){
        DataTable dtConditions = new DataTable(); 

        DataColumn firstParameterID = new DataColumn("firstParameterID ", typeof(int));
        dtConditions.Columns.Add(firstParameterID);

        DataColumn secondParameterID = new DataColumn("secondParameterID ", typeof(int));
        dtConditions.Columns.Add(secondParameterID ); 
         /*
         * more columns and rows...
         */
        return dtConditions;
    }
```

My question is: How do I put it or can I put it in a separate class file named dataTableConditions.cs....

I created a class file and here is what I have, but what next?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;

namespace myHomeworkProject
{
    class dataTableConditions
    {
        //How do I make this class and later how can I access its rows, I mean, how can I assign values to these rows later from other methods?
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean as a class property?

Comment: i guess you were told to have another class that store your `DataTable` methods. its my first time that i heard `DataTable as a class`?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, as I am a beginner :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you're creating the following

```
 DataTable dtConditions = new DataTable();
```

You shoulk create a `DataTable` class. The class can look like:

```html
using  System.Collections.Generic;

namespace someNamespace {

    public class DataTable {

        public List<DataColumn> Columns {get;set;}
    }

}
```

`Columns` is a `List` object storing the different `DataColumns`. You can also create a `List` property that stores the different rows.

.Net framework also includes a default implementation of a data table class. This [link](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable) shows you how the "API" of the class looks like. This [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30490/How-to-Manually-Create-a-Typed-DataTable) describes how to write your own datatable class.

Hope that helps.